# Did the IBMQ Job Download change of ZIP results

Tags: qiskit, ibm-quantum-devices, ibm-q-experience

today I realized the contents of the Zip File changed when downloading a completed job. Now when I download a job on IBMQ I get a zip file containing a info.json and a result.txt.
And I checked a job from November 2022 and the Zip contained an info.json, an input.json and an output.json.
Does somebody has the same experience? I could imagine that this had a major impact on Software depending on these results. I'm curious if some of you have information about that exact change.